# Weighted sum of differences of vector elements

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

During some matlab experiments with vectors and matrices, I found that the following expression

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^N C_{ijk} (x_i-x_j)(x_j-x_k)$$

should always be nonpositive, as long as all $C_{ijk}\geq 0$. I tried to prove it, thinking that it should be elementary, but I just keep failing, which is making me crazy..

If all $C_{ijk}=1$, then it's indeed trivial since the expression is then equal to

$$N\left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right)^2 - N^2\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 \leq 0.$$

But how do I prove it with general $C_{ijk} \geq 0$?

Comment: it is false, choose $C_{123}=1, C_{321}=2, C_{312}=3, C_{213}=4$ and $x_3=0$, the hessian matrix of $x_1, x_2$ is $2\times [-3, 5; 5 ,-7]$, determinant is not positive.

Answer (score 2):

When $N=2,$ the sum is:
$$S = C_{121}(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_1)+C_{212}(x_2-x_1)(x_1-x_2)\leq 0$$
easy. When $N=3$, the non-square terms (or when $i,j,k$ are distinct)
$$T = C_{123}(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)+C_{132}(x_1-x_3)(x_3-x_2)+$$
$$+C_{213}(x_2-x_1)(x_1-x_3)+C_{231}(x_2-x_3)(x_3-x_1)+$$
$$+C_{312}(x_3-x_1)(x_1-x_2)+C_{321}(x_3-x_2)(x_2-x_1),$$
so unfortunately your conjecture is false so long as there is no restrictions on $C_{ijk}$'s. First, just fix whatever distinct $x_1,x_2,x_3$ you want and then make the term in front of a positive term out of the possible $6$ above to be as large as possible so the entire sum becomes positive, even after adding the negative squares. If for example $x_1,x_2,x_3 = 1,2,3,$ then pick $C_{321} = 10^{1000}$ and pick other $C$ values to be small.

There might however be a natural restrictions on the $C's$ to make this true - I have a feeling that requiring $C_{ijk}$ is constant under cyclic permutation  on the indices might make up an interesting problem.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexamples - I was silly, using only randomly generated $C_{ijk}$, which is actually a very particular choice (still, it would be interesting to see if the claim holds "with high probability").

It is an interesting suggestion to consider $C_{ijk}$ invariant under cyclic permutations. In fact, a particular case I was originally interest in would be $C_{ijk} = A_{ij} B_{jk}$ with $A$, $B$ symmetric. I have the tendency to (again:) believe that then the claim holds, but still truggling to find a proof.

Comment: @Jan Haskovec You can ask new question with that or better yet write your expression as a quadratic form $x^TCx$ and it is non-positive if and only if $C$ is non-positive definite.